# Simplifying query

Tags: sql, oracle19c

Is it possible to achieve the same result with a simpler query?

```
SELECT
    DEPARTAMENTO,
    COALESCE(SUM(MES_01), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_01,
    COALESCE(SUM(MES_02), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_02,
    COALESCE(SUM(MES_03), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_03

FROM
    (
         SELECT
            DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DESCRICAO DEPARTAMENTO,
            FALTAS AS MES_01,
            0 AS MES_02,
            0 AS MES_03
        FROM
DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH  JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO ON DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH.DEPARTAMENTO = DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID        WHERE
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 12)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DESCRICAO DEPARTAMENTO,
            0 AS MES_01,
            FALTAS AS MES_02,
            0 AS MES_03
        FROM
DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH  JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO ON DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH.DEPARTAMENTO = DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID        WHERE
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 11)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DESCRICAO DEPARTAMENTO,
            0 AS MES_01,
            0 AS MES_02,
            FALTAS AS MES_03
        FROM
DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH  JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO ON DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH.DEPARTAMENTO = DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID        WHERE
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 10)

    ) subquery GROUP BY departamento
    union all
    SELECT
    'Total Geral' AS DEPARTAMENTO,
    COALESCE(SUM(MES_01), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_01,
    COALESCE(SUM(MES_02), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_02,
    COALESCE(SUM(MES_03), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_03
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DESCRICAO DEPARTAMENTO,
            FALTAS AS MES_01,
            0 AS MES_02,
            0 AS MES_03
        FROM
DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH  JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO ON DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH.DEPARTAMENTO = DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID        WHERE
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 12)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DESCRICAO DEPARTAMENTO,
            0 AS MES_01,
            FALTAS AS MES_02,
            0 AS MES_03
        FROM
DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH  JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO ON DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH.DEPARTAMENTO = DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID        WHERE
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 11)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DESCRICAO DEPARTAMENTO,
            0 AS MES_01,
            0 AS MES_02,
            FALTAS AS MES_03
        FROM
DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH  JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO ON DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH.DEPARTAMENTO = DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID        WHERE
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 10)
    ) subquery;
```

This query sums a field "faltas" by each month and each "departamentos" and brings a table like this

| Departamento | Total_mes_01 | Total_mes_02 | Total_mes_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Administration | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| Logistics | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| Total Geral | 7 | 6 | 2 |

The problem is that in real world I am bringing 13 months and is very annoing when I have to  make any change, but I could not simplify it with my current knowledge

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please format your result table as a table (not as html) so that it is readable: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow. I’m guessing that most/all of the UNIONs could be replaced by CASE statements in a single SELECT

Comment: @NickW Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* to calculate multiple sums covering different months in a single query. This is a technique where you place a `CASE` expression inside a `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, or other aggregate function to limit the data included in the result.

You can also use `GROUP BY ROLLUP` to get a total across all departments from the same query. In the final select list, a `CASE WHEN GROUPING(...) ...` expression can be used to inject an appropriate totals label. `GROUPING()` can also be used in the `ORDER BY`.

This allows everything to be reduced down to a single select. Something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(D.DESCRICAO) = 1
        THEN 'Total Geral'
        ELSE D.DESCRICAO
        END AS DEPARTAMENTO,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE 
        WHEN I.DATA >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -12)
        AND I.DATA < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -11)
        THEN I.FALTAS END), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_01,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE
        WHEN I.DATA >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -11)
        AND I.DATA < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -10)
        THEN I.FALTAS END), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_02,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE
        WHEN I.DATA >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -10)
        AND I.DATA < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -9)
        THEN I.FALTAS END), 0) AS TOTAL_MES_03
FROM DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH I
JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO D
    ON I.DEPARTAMENTO = D.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID
WHERE I.DATA >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -12) -- Limit the overall select
AND I.DATA < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -9)
GROUP BY ROLLUP (D.DESCRICAO)
ORDER BY
    GROUPING(D.DESCRICAO), -- 0 = details first, 1 = totals last
    D.DESCRICAO
```

I also made a few other changes to the query:

1. The `TRUNC()` and `ADD_MONTHS()` have been used to calculate start and end dates for each month instead of converting to and from text
2. An overall `WHERE` condition was added to limit the selected data to just the three months of interest.  By pre-calculating the date limits and comparing I.DATA directly with those date limits, oracle should be able to use available indexes to efficiently access the required range of data.
3. Aliases were defined for the tables references and used to qualify all column references.

Sample results:

| DEPARTAMENTO | TOTAL_MES_01 | TOTAL_MES_02 | TOTAL_MES_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAA | 33.33 | 777.77 | 3333.33 |
| BBBB | 88.88 | 0 | 99.99 |
| Total Geral | 122.21 | 777.77 | 3433.32 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AhzXsEUg) for a demo.

Comment: I used ChatGPT to improve the code you provided me, thanks. Unfortunately, StackOverFlow does not let me post the code here

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code to indicate what I meant by using CASE statements rather than UNIONing SQL statements, not meant to be a working example…

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 12)
    THEN FALTAS ELSE 0 
END AS MES_01,
CASE 
    WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') = ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY'), - 11)
    THEN FALTAS ELSE 0
END AS MES_02
…
FROM DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH  
JOIN DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO ON     DW_FATO_INDICADORES_RH.DEPARTAMENTO =     DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO.DW_DIM_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRAO_ID
```

It would also make your code more readable if you aliased your tables